# Getting ArrayList<String> from arrays.xml file cast issue

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have to get an array stored in arrays.xml as ArrayList

```
String arrayNames[]=MyActivity.this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names;
ArrayList<String> namesList=(ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(arrayNames));
```

this cause

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

because cast from List to `ArrayList` seems deniend due to different implementations of List.

I need to pass `ArrayList<String>` so I cannot change `ArrayList<String> namesList` in `List<String> namesList`.

wondering if is there a better way to convert `String` in `ArrayList<String>` without write manually a method that iterates all array Entries and put all them in an `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast it this way, declare a new `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> namesList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayNames)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> namesList=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayNames));
```

Comment: We were typing at the same time. I didn't see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the TypedArray

```
Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
TypedArray namesList = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.names);
```